# Rails - Migrating data to another DB with different IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have a scenario in which I need to dump/transfer data of one user from my Rails App to another database of same configuration and tables. For instance, The application is built as

```
  class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :depots
    has_many :users
  end

  class Depot < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    has_many :products
  end

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
  end

  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :depot
  end
```

My requirement is, if companyA stops paying, I want to dump their data into another DB (databse2 for instance) to keep my actual DB clean and once they come back and start paying, I want this data back.

Second requirement is, database2 can already have some data in it. So I need to retain all the records and I want to change the IDs of companyA (as there can already be a company with the same ID) while saving in to database2 keeping associations intact. It might seem silly to do this, but that is my requirement.
I am using **Postgres** as my application DB.
 Any helps???

Comment: It sounds messy, but so long as you don't change any of the IDs and don't alter your sequence generators you're going to be fine. Never re-issue IDs. It's just plain reckless. You run the risk of one company "inheriting" the data of another because of a simple mistake.

Comment: I was trying to clone the records and then save it to new DB using ActiveRecord and gems like Amoeba,  but that messes up all the application as I have a lot of validations in the models for nil parent-id constraints.

Comment: The first question you need to ask yourself is if the storage overhead is crippling enough you really need to do this in the first place. The second thing to investigate is if you can simply serialize everything and dump it out as a file, then de-serialize it later back into your database. You could do this into JSON with gzip as an example. There's no explicit need for a second database unless you need this data online, and if you do, keep it in the master.

Comment: Whatever you do here the more low-level the operation is the better. Preserve IDs at all cost. Do not fill in holes. Avoid using models since they will alter the created/updated timestamp fields.

Comment: I am going to have several companies in future with loads of data. Keeping un-necessary data in DB is an overhead. Secondly its my clients' requirement being very less arguable :-(. I tried to save it as JSON as well but my problem is IDs. If I get JSON data back into my original DB, There is a possibility of breakage while parsing it. Benefit of second DB is, I can connect it to ActiveRecord at any time to show it to the company.

Comment: If there's a problem of "breakage" then your serialization and restoration routine doesn't work properly. Fix the issue, test that it works under a wide variety of circumstances, and you'll be fine. If you're dealing with "loads of data" then I'd suggest that two databases isn't enough. You should look at sharing and migrating companies between shards depending on their usage patterns and demands.

Comment: I have got 50+ tables approximately containing data of all the associations. Dont you think parsing a JSON file of this much content will not work fine? Breakage  means I have validations on approximately all models to check for the existence of their parent and their attributes.

Comment: JSON is just a convenient container. It could be a series of CSV files or a `.sql` file containing `INSERT` statements, it doesn't really matter so long as you can properly capture and encode everything, then use that file to restore your data reliably at any point in the future.

Comment: Sounds understandable. What about the IDs if these are taken after some time. For example, I change the DB or add a new one to my application and want to restore the JSON for company having ID 5. And there is already a company with ID 5 now in my DB?

Comment: Why would IDs be re-issued? Postgres, unless told otherwise, issues these once and once only per table. Never, ever re-use IDs as a matter of policy. When you create a new database, roll over the previous sequences.

Comment: I understand. All I can do is now, try to explain it to my client if he agrees on it. Otherwise we ll have to do something for the IDs... fingers crossed ... Thanks for your help @tadman

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here worth investigating:

1. Output everything in a singular JSON file that encodes everything the client had in the database, complete with ID fields.
2. Dump out a series of CSV files that can be imported on the destination server.
3. Dump out a single `.sql` file that will properly restore the data simply by running it.

The first option is the most elegant, but probably requires the most work. It gives you the ability to archive your data in a neat, tidy file that's easily parsed.

The second option might be fine or could be severely ugly depending on the sorts of data you have. If there's any binary data involved that's probably not going to work, but for clean, text-only columns and tabular data it's usually fairly efficient. The advantage here is you can selectively load in parts of your data without having to commit to parsing all of it.

The third option isn't easily parsed, you need to restore it to be able to use it, but it does make insertion really, really simple. You will only have to write an archiver, no specific restoration tool is required.

Whatever approach you take you'll need to be absolutely certain that ID numbers are never, ever reissued. Do not reset your sequence generators to fill in holes, and when moving databases port these over as well and test that they're set correctly. The last thing you need is ID conflicts.

If you're really worried about ID conflicts you might want to switch to non-numeric IDs, like use a UUID for everything where conflicts are basically irrelevant, though this does not come without a cost.

Comment: Lets give it a try and see if things get sorted.